# Excel Cell Location Using Row And Column Numbers VB.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have a vb.net program that is reading and writing to an excel file.  I need to use the "Range" function for a specific task, but it requires the actual value of the cell.  All I have is the Row and Column number which varies depending on what the user is doing.  How do I get the actual cell location based off of the row/column number without hard coding it.

Example:
Row 1, Column 1 = "A1"
Row 5, Column 27 = "AA5"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Workbook("Name").Sheets("Name").Cells(RowVariable, ColVariable).Address`

Comment: With **Option Strict Off** (not default, not standard practice), this code will work; however, early binding is preferable. FWIW, the OP needs "the actual value of the cell", not the address.

Comment: _"How do I get the actual cell location based off of the row/column "_ but I agree with you...

Answer (score 1):

In vb.net you need to convert each object explicitly as follows.

```
CellValue  = CType(CType(CType(ExcelApp.Workbooks("WorkbookName"), Excel.Workbook).Worksheets("SheetName"), Excel.Worksheet).Cells(rowNum, colNum), Excel.Range).Value
```

Ideally you would already have variables for the workbook and worksheet which would make this previous statement more readable. For example:

```
Dim wbk As Excel.Workbook = CType(ExcelApp.Workbooks("WorkbookName"), Excel.Workbook)
Dim wst As Excel.Worksheet = CType(wbk.Worksheets("SheetName"), Excel.Worksheet)
Dim CellValue As Object = CType(wst.Cells(rowNum, colNum), Excel.Range).Value
```

Note: Substitute your Excel Application variable for `ExcelApp`.